# Plotly name argument

Tags: python, plot

I've found the code attached below to plot a time series of different countries. My questions is the following: why in the code is needed to use the `name = rowname` and the for loop as well?

```
name = rowname
)for rowname in df1.index]
```

Complete code source:

```
#plot all rows
traces = [go.Scatter(
    x = df1.columns,
    y = df1.loc[rowname],
    mode = 'lines',
    name = rowname
)for rowname in df1.index]  

layout = go.Layout(title = 'Purchase parity power by country')
figure = go.Figure(data = traces, layout = layout)
pyo.plot(figure)
```

I want to understand as for me copy paste from anotherone's code doesn't bring value. The part that I specially don't understand is why the code creator used `df1.index` for the loop. How to understand that part?

Thanks for your help community!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this reference](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/#scatter-and-line-plot-with-goscatter). I think you'll see that the `name` argument will set the name for your data series or "trace".

In your example, it looks like they are creating a new scatter series (trace) for each row in your dataframe. By setting the `name` to the `rowname`, then you will see this as the name on your legend and tooltips. You can set the name to the row index or use that index to index into a pretty print name for each row.

Comment: hello @gnodab! Thanks for your response I think I need a bit more time with documentation to understand what I'm doing! Thanks for bringing some light on this.

Comment: Yep. It’s always good to start with the documentation. But it’s not always clear. Let me know if I can help more.